# Destructor call during object initialization?

Tags: c++

Given the code below, why would I get an error about A's destructor being private?  Obviously it is private, but I don't understand why initializing B's A object instance in this way would cause the destructor of A to be called.

Apologies for any typos, I'm recreating the code from memory from a non-networked system and don't have a compiler.

```
class A
{
    public:
        A(int val) : x(val) {}

    private:
        int x;
        ~A() {}
};

class B
{
    public:
        B() : aInstance() {}

    private:
        A aInstance;
};

int main()
{
    B b;
}
```

Comment: Can't do it for stack-based objects (even indirectly.) There's a good discussion of private destructor usage and restrictions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631783/what-is-the-use-of-having-destructor-as-private

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initializing itself doesn't involve using the dtor, but the instance of `B` is destroyed at the end of `main`. The `B` contains an `A`, so when the `B` is destroyed,the `A` must be destroyed as well -- but `A`'s dtor isn't available, so the code to do that can't be generated.

Answer (score 2):

Since `B` class contains an instance of `A` class (as private field `aInstance`), it has to be destroyed when instance of `B` is destroyed.

That's exactly what happens inside your `main`. As`B b;` is allocated and created on stack, it gets out of scope when function ends and must be destroyed, like every local object in C++.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of main(), when B goes out of scope, how is B supposed to deallocate the member of type A?

It can't, because you declared the destructor private.

Comment: It isn't main that has the problem it is B, in which the compiler will automatically create the destructor that needs to delete the A it doesn't have access to the destructor of.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is that `A` is a member of `B`.  The type `B`'s default generated constructor must be rule call the destructor for each of it's fields.  Hence there is an implicit call to `A` destructor here to which it doesn't have access and you get the error

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the destructor for `A` is being called from within a constructor. The destructor to `A` is probably being called when the `b` goes out of scope in main (when the program terminates.)

Answer (score 0):

It is actually B that needs access to the destructor and not main().

If you make B a friend of A it will work. If you make `main()` a friend of A it will not compile.

Because the instance of A is declared as "automatic", i.e. it is a class member, its deletion will not happen in the destructor of B but will happen during B's destruction. However this is considered to be in the scope of the access of B as a class.