# Why I got C4624(base class destructor is inaccessible) when using composition instead of inheritance?

Tags: c++, destructor

The following code will cause [C4624](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fthdf523.aspx). But you can see D is not the sub class of B. Why still got this warning? Thanks!

```
class B {
// Uncomment the following line to resolve.
// public:
~B();
};

class D  {B b;};   // C4624 B's destructor not public
```

More details about the warning:

[C4624](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fthdf523.aspx): 'derived class' : destructor could not be generated because a base class destructor is inaccessible

A destructor was not accessible in a base class and was therefore not generated for a derived class. Any attempt to create an object of this type on the stack will cause a compiler error.

Comment: The error message seems buggy, but the error is legitimate if you ignore the "base class" part.

Comment: Why don't you want `B`'s destructor public?

Comment: I understand this is not correct and I do not want to do this actually. I only trying what posted here:http://stackoverflow.com/a/13576544/304115 po

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class members are initialised by the class's constructor(s) and destroyed by its destructor. Their constructor(s) and destructor must therefore be accessible within those functions.

In your example, `B` has a private destructor, and is therefore not accessible to the destructor of `D`, which needs it to destroy its member of type `B`.

I've no idea why the error message refers to a "base class" though. If you get that error message from the code you posted, then your compiler could do with some improvements to its diagnostics.

Comment: I got this warning in Visual studio 2012. I just wondering why the warning said "base class".

Comment: Most likely, the compiler writer reused the error code without checking whether it was appropriate for its new context. It's a common error, and [can be very expensive](http://archive.eiffel.com/doc/manuals/technology/contract/ariane/).

Answer (score 0):

Because class `D` isn't friend of class `B` and class `B` isn't part of class `D`. This means that `B`'s private parts can't be accessed from scope of `D`. This also means that you can't create an object of type `D` or `B` on the stack since it will require the destructor of `B` to be accessible when the object gets out of scope and should be deleted. Note, the error message seems incorrect, like was accurately mentioned by @R.MartinhoFernandes. Private destructors can be of use if you manage the memory by yourself([like described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631783/what-is-the-use-of-having-destructor-as-private)).