# Determining whether a C++ class has a private destructor

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor, private

Let's say I have the following code:

```cpp
class Example
{
#ifndef PRIVATE_DESTRUCTOR
public:
#endif
    ~Example() { }
public:
    friend class Friend;
};

class Friend
{
public:
    void Member();
};

void Friend::Member()
{
    std::printf("Example's destructor is %s.\n",
        IsDestructorPrivate<Example>::value ? "private" : "public");
}
```

Is it possible to implement the `IsDestructorPrivate` template above to determine whether a class's destructor is `private` or `protected`?

In the cases I'm working with, the only times I need to use this `IsDestructorPrivate` are within places that have access to such a private destructor, if it exists.  It doesn't necessarily exist.  It is permissible for IsDestructorPrivate to be a macro rather than a template (or be a macro that resolves to a template).  C++11 is fine.

Comment: why would you create private destructor?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to check accessibility. And ideally you should not write code that depends on that.

Comment: @mohaned for singleton-like behaviour maybe?

Comment: @mohaned here is a better answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/631783/3093378

Comment: @mohaned - `why would you create private destructor?` So that you can control how clients create/destroy instances of your class.

Comment: Sounds totally wrong. Why do you construct a class with a private destructor. Inhibit the construction in the first place.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631783/what-is-the-use-of-having-destructor-as-private (vsoftco beat me to it)

Comment: @DieterLücking: You probably would make the constructor private in that case, too. Of course *completely* inhibiting construction would probably make the class useless (as would completely inhibiting destruction), although there can be exceptions (classes which are only defined for the type).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the `std::is_destructible` type trait like the example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class Foo {
  ~Foo() {}
};

int main() {
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_destructible<Foo>::value << std::endl;
}
```

[<kbd>**LIVE DEMO**</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee38f939dd3e95c0)

`std::is_destructible<T>::value` will be equal to `false` if the destructor of `T` is `deleted` or `private` and `true` otherwise.

Comment: Damn.  That doesn't exist in Visual Studio 2010 and plain doesn't work in Visual Studio 2013.  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/811436/vc-is-destructible-doesnt-work

Comment: Also, the Standard seems unclear on whether std::is_destructible is, in fact, supposed to even return false for private/protected destructors.

Comment: @Myria as you've already discovered Visual studio is buggy on using `std::is_destructible` type trait. IMHO though, I think the standard is clear that `std::is_destructible<T>::value` will return `false` if destructor is not accessible since it requires that *expression `std::declval<U&>().˜U()` is well-formed when treated as an unevaluated operand*, where in the case of `~U()` is inaccessible is not. Alternatively, in visual studio you could use boost to overcome this misfeature.

Comment: Before posting this, I checked the Git repository copy of the standard; that wording was unclear.  I didn't see anything specifying ''in which context'' the well-formedness of the expression is checked.  `std::declval<U&>().~U()` is well-formed in `class U` or `friend` scope.  For example, http://pastebin.com/j3BvWkcm

Comment: An expression is well defined if it doesn't make the program ill defined. To that end, if expression `std::declval<U&>().~U()` is evaluated in a context where destructor of `U` is accessible (e.g., a member function of `U`, a declared `friend` of `U` etc.) then it is well formed and is going to be evaluated to `void`. If it is evaluated in context where destructor of `U` is inaccessible expression is ill-formed because simply the program can't compile. Type-traits use SFINAE. That is, if `std::is_destructible<T>::value` is evaluated in a context where `T`'s destructor's is inaccessible...

Comment: ... only the trait that makes `std::is_destructible<T>::value == false` is going to be instantiated because expression `std::declval<U&>().~U()` when destructor of `U` is inaccessible can't compile/evaluated. On the other hand when `std::is_destructible<T>::value` is used in a context where destructor of `T` is accessible the type trait where `std::is_destructible<T>::value == true` is going to be instantiated because expression `std::declval<U&>().~U()` can be evaluated to `void` it is compilable. HTH

Comment: @Myria To clear things up more, try to put the expression `decltype(std::declval<U&>().~U()) *ptr = nulptr;` somewhere in `main`. You'll see that program doesn't compile due to this expression (i.e., `std::declval<U&>().~U()` is not well form thus it breaks the program). On the other hand if `U`'s destructor is `public` (i.e., accessible) it compiles fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59443/discussion-between-myria-and-40two).