# Vector of class object with private constructor and destructor?

Tags: c++, private-members

Defining the classes A with private constructor and destructor (it should be so!) and B as a friend class, how can I creat a vector of A objects in B and fill it with the function addA(). I got the error "error C2248: "A::~A": No access to private members whose declaration was made in the A class".

```
class A
{
private:
    A();
    A(const std::string& name, const float& num);
    ~A();
public:
    friend class B;
private:
    std::string name_;
    float num_;
};

A::A() 
{
    name_ = "NoName";
    num_ = 0.0;
}
A::A(const std::string& name, const float& num)
{
    name_ = name;
    num_ = num;
}
A::~A()
{   
}

class B
{
public:
    B();
    ~B();
    void addA(const std::string name, const float num);
private:
    vector<A> vecA;
};

B::B() 
{
}
B::~B() 
{
}
void B::addA(const std::string name, const float num)
{
    A a(name, num);
    vecA.push_back(a);
}

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.addA("Name", 1.0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity; why would you ever want a private destructor?

Comment: Why are your constructor and destructor `private` anyway?

Comment: While `B` is a friend of `A`, `std::vector<A>` is *not* a friend of `A`, and therefore can't access private members of `A`. Like for example the destructor it needs due to its internal life-time handling of the objects it stores.

Comment: @Clearer [What is the use of having destructor as private?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/631783/10147399)

Comment: I believe you could create a vector of pointers to A instead of vector of objects to A. But you will have to handle the memory when you add or delete items in the vector.

Comment: @Clearer and @ CoryKramer: Unfortunately that's part of the assignment!

Comment: Excuse me, is the assignment _actually_ saying that `A`'s constructors and destructor must be _private_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I create a vector of A objects in B [...] ?

You can't do that. While `B` is a `friend` of `A`, `std::vector` is *not* a `friend` of `A`, which means that it cannot access `private` members of `A`, e.g., constructor, which is required for a vector to work.

However, if you are okay with a little indirection, little potential performance hit and a change in your signature, you can replace the not-working `std::vector<A>` with a workig `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A, deleter>>`.

It's important to note that plain `std::unique_ptr` will not work here. It has a similar problem to `std::vector` - it cannot access `private` destructor of `A`. One way to work around it is to outsource the job of constructing and destructing of `A`s entirely to `B` - via explicit construction and destruction, that is:

- `new A(name, num)`
- `static void deleter_a(A* a) { delete a; }`

in `B`'s scope.

Now we can do:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A, std::function<void(A*)>>> vecA;
```

instead of: `std::vector<A>` or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>`. This is important - neither `std::unique_ptr` nor `std::vector` construct *or* destruct your `A`s. `B` is entirely responsible for constructing (`new A(name, num)`) and destructing (`static void deleter_a(A* a) { delete a; }`) `A`s.

Full `B` class:

```
class B {
public:
    B() {};  // or = default
    ~B() {}; // or = default
    void addA(const std::string name, const float num);

private:
    static void deleter_a(A* a) { delete a; }
    using deleter_a_t = void(A*);
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A, std::function<deleter_a_t>>> vecA;
};

void B::addA(const std::string name, const float num) {
    vecA.push_back(std::unique_ptr<A, std::function<deleter_a_t>>{
            new A(name, num), std::function<deleter_a_t>{deleter_a}
    });
}
```

Comment: You're right! Do you think that "vector< std::shared_ptr<A> > VecA" may help? If so, how can I then fill it with objects! 
Or what other container instead of vector you suggest for storing A objects, which can work here?
The questions may be naive, but I am new to C++! ;)

Comment: Nope.  That would require `std::shared_pointer<A>` to be a friend of `A`.    Consider giving `A` public constructors and destructors.   You currently have a contradiction of a class with private constructors and destructor, while wanting to use them as if they have public constructors and destructor.   Compilers are required to reject that contradiction - since, by declaring things private, you have told it to do so.

Comment: @Hossein `std::shared_ptr<A>` will have the same problem - it cannot use `private` members, which, in this case, are needed to construct and destruct an object. However, I'm editing the question in order to make it work.

Comment: @Hossein no problem, happy to help. If the above solution solved your problem, consider accepting this answer by clicking the tick below the score in order to inform future visitors of your question that this solution indeed solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

While @Fureeish has a neat solution, here's a slightly simpler alternative: just wrap it.

```
class AccessPrivate;

class PrivStuff
{
private:
    PrivStuff() {}
    ~PrivStuff() {}
public:
    friend class AccessPrivate;

    std::string m_data{};
};

class AccessPrivate
{
public:
    AccessPrivate() = default;
    ~AccessPrivate() = default;

    PrivStuff m_priv;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<AccessPrivate> myvec;
    myvec.resize(4);

    for (auto& stuff : myvec)
    {
        stuff.m_priv.m_data = "heya";
    }

}
```

If you need something more complicated, like passing in arguments, just add an equivalent constructor to `AccessPrivate` and there you go.  You can essentially treat `AccessPrivate` almost like the actual private class, just one level of indirection.

Comment: I employed the idea of @Fureeish! thank you by the way :)

Comment: This answer is much better, it does not introduce a very complicated indirection, to not talk about the cratering performance of `unique_ptr`!

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what the other answers say, it is possible to do this without any extra indirection.

`std::vector` doesn't directly call the constructor and the destructor, but uses an allocator. If you want an `std::vector` to manage A objects, you just need to provide it an allocator that implements the `construct` and `destroy` functions, and that is either a friend of A or a nested class of B (since B is already a friend of A).

Example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

class A {

    A() = default;
    ~A() = default;

    friend class B;
    
};

class B {
    
    template<typename T>
    struct custom_alloc : std::allocator<T> {
        
        template<typename U, typename... Args>
        void construct(U* p, Args&&... args){
            ::new(const_cast<void*>(static_cast<const volatile void*>(p))) U(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
        
        template<typename U>
        void destroy(U* p){
            if constexpr (std::is_array_v<U>){
                for(auto& elem : *p){
                    (destroy)(std::addressof(elem));
                }
            } else {
                p->~U();
            }
        }
        
    };
    
public:

    std::vector<A,custom_alloc<A>> vec;
    
    void new_A(){
        vec.push_back(A());
    }
    
};
```

For the implementation of `construct` and `destroy`, I used an equivalent implementation of the c++20 versions of [`std::destroy_at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/destroy_at) and [`std::construct_at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/construct_at). I suspect that `destroy` is overkill and just a call to the destructor would be sufficient, but I'm not sure.